# How to return 2 decimal place for float data type in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, backend

```
class Node{
int data;
string food_name;
float price;
int quantity;

public:
Node* next;

//initialization list
//assignment operator
//constructor
Node(int d,string f_name, float p, int q){
    this->data = d;
    this->food_name = f_name;
    this->price = ceil(p *100)/100;
    this->quantity = q;
    this->next = NULL;
}
string getData(){
    return to_string(data) +": " + food_name +"\t\t\t"+ to_string(quantity) +" x RM" + to_string(price) +"\n";
}


//to access the private member in the Node
friend class List;

};
```

always get an output of
1: Chicken Rice 1 x RM6.000000
how can I set the precision to 2 decimal places ? any help would be much appreciate

Comment: `std::ostringstream ss; ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << price; return ss.str();`

Comment: Note that `ceil(p*100)/100` usually won't give you two decimal places. Floating-point values are represented in **binary**, so you can't really control their **decimal** representations. That's why calculations involving money are usually done with integer types (holding, say, the value in cents)

Comment: @Eljay preferrably use `return std::move(ss).str()` to allow to transfer the memory allocated by the `std::ostringstream` to the string created. This only works starting C++20, but it doesn't hurt with previous standards...

Comment: Floating point math is inherently inprecise. You should store all your prices as integers in cents and only convert it to float when printing. Otherwise you will gain or loose a cent at some point and any comparison will have to accept a slight error.

Comment: `this->price = ceil(p *100)/100;` -- I know this is a toy program, but as mentioned, don't use `double` or `float` for monetary calculations -- either work in integer, or get a library that does exact decimal math.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow And losing that cent, when multiplied, can get a financial company sued by its patrons.  That's why floating point is forbidden to be used in those circumstances.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow -- floating point arithmetic is exact and well defined. The problem is that floating-point numbers aren't real numbers, so all the intuition we've developed over the years is wrong.

Comment: @PeteBecker It has a limited precision and it's well defined how it rounds. So everything is perfectly deterministic and you can compute the amount of error any math will have. But except for a limited set of numbers just converting decimal input to floating point will only get you close to the input. And from then on the error compounds.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow -- that's essentially what I said: floating-point numbers are not real numbers, and if you expect them to behave like real numbers you're going to be constantly surprised. Converting decimal input to floating-point is one of the biggest areas where this comes up, because most **textual** representations of numbers, while valid representations of real numbers, are not valid representations of floating-point values. If you persist in thinking of them as real numbers, yes, the error accumulates, but the error is not in the code, but in the understanding of what it does.